# How to prevent users to redirect to next page before the answer the question

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup

I would like the users to fill in the feedback form before they try to navigate away from the current page

I added following code in angular

```
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (window.addEventListener) {

                window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){         
                            scope.showForm = true;
                 });
            }
```

It shows the form but the page gets redirect to the next page (I mean, to the page the user has clicked link on).

If I add `event.returnValue="something"` it works, but then first it shows the alert and then it shows the custom form. I have tried

`$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function( event ) {
                var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")
                if (!answer) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });`

but this doesn't work as well.

Please help how can I show the form, prevent redirect without alerT?

Comment: Hi, you should provide a more functional example; you're referring to parts that you didn't post.

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. As I have mentioned, I am using unload function to listen if user is going away from current page. Onunload, I would like to show the custom feedback form. The form is shown but the page is then redirected to the another page. i would like to stop the redirect before user fill the form or chose to cancel the fill the form.